# How does path integral formulation explain bound states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

It seems to me that the intuitive explanation of path integrals in quantum mechanics describes scattering processes only.

You have a particle going from A to B and you compute the probability amplitude to go from A to B.

But in a bound state, such as an infinite potential well or an hydrogen atom, it doesn't seem natural to consider a particle going from one place to other. Specially if the state is stationary.

How is the path integral useful in bound states?

Comment: The path integral formulation is mathematically rigorous in "imaginary time" (see the [Feynman-Kac formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)). That means it is suited to study spectral properties, such as eigenvalues (and thus bound states), maybe more than to study the "real time" dynamics. See for example this [paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula), as an application of the path integral to the ground state energy and energy crossing of the Rabi model.

Comment: @yuggib Thanks, but my question was more oriented to an intuitive explanation.

Comment: There are loads of articles in Googlespace on path integral treatment of the simple harmonic oscillator. This might be a good start.

Comment: What if I posed the question thus: Consider a QFT of a proton field and an electron field. Initial state: Free electron and free proton --> Final state Hydrogen atom in the 1s state. How would one calculate this transition amplitude?

Comment: Once I can compute that, I could use the optical theorem to calculate the one-loop correction from such bound states to the Moller-like scattering of the electron and proton. Going that way, I think there might be a path (forgive the pun) to incorporate the effects of bound states into the formalism.

Comment: The question I posed above is problematic to me, since the final state is not a "fluctuation" off the QFT vacuum, but a _bound state_. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't know how to describe it in terms of the creation and annihilation operators of the proton and electron.

Answer (score 5):

The Hydrogen atom can be solved exactly in the path integral formalism, see for example [Fortschritte der Physik **30** 401](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/83/83.pdf).

There is no conceptual problem to compute a probability amplitude for a system with bound-states in this formalism. For example, if the system is initially in a state $\psi(x)$ localized around $A=0$, the probability amplitude $a(B)$ to find the particle in $B$ after a time $t$ is 
$$a_t(B)\propto \int dx' K_t(B|x')\psi(x') $$ 
where $K$ is given by the path integral
$$K_t(x|x')=\int_{x(0)=x'}^{x(t)=x} Dx(\tau) \,e^{i S[x(\tau)]}$$
with $S$ the classical action (of the Hydrogen atom problem). If $B$ is very far from $A$, and if $\psi$ is overlap manly on the bound-states (localized around A), this amplitude will be very small, as expected. If $\psi$ overlap mainly on the scattering states, the probability might be much closer to one.